# Issue while row hiding in Group By Nattable

Tags: swt, jface, nattable, groupingby

I am using a nattable with rows that represent different objects, including group by objects and an another objects.

[image: Nattable - Before Issue]

When I tried to hide row number 302, which represents an object, it is being hidden as expected. However, seeing an issue with row 303, which represents a group by object. Specifically, it seems that the group by object label is still visible, but the rows after row 303 are repeating the same group by object.

[image: Nattable -Issue]

Im using the following code :

```java
bodyDataLayer = new GroupByDataLayer<>(groupByModel,GlazedLists.threadSafeList(GlazedLists.eventList(data)),    columnPropertyAccessor,configRegistry);

this.bodyDataProvider = (ListDataProvider) bodyDataLayer.getDataProvider();

GlazedListsEventLayer glazedlist = new GlazedListsEventLayer<>(bodyDataLayer,
                    ((GroupByDataLayer<T>) bodyDataLayer).getTreeList());


  dataChangeLayer = createDataChangeLayer(rowIdAccessor, bodyDataProvider, glazedlist);
            
columnReorderLayer = new ColumnReorderLayer(dataChangeLayer, columnReorderDefaultConfig);
   

 columnHideShowLayer = new ResizeColumnHideShowLayer(columnReorderLayer, bodyDataLayer);    

RowHideShowLayer rowHideShowLayer = new RowHideShowLayer(columnHideShowLayer);
```

Is there any way to resolve this issue. Help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using the `RowHideShowLayer` which hides a row by row index. This is not working correctly in combination with GlazedLists features like GroupBy. For this you need to use the `GlazedListsRowHideShowLayer` which hides rows via row object ids.

The usage is shown in the [NatTable Examples Application](https://www.eclipse.org/nattable/documentation.php?page=examples_application) in ***Tutorial Examples - GlazedLists - GlazedListsRowHideShowExample*** or in ***Tutorial Examples - Integration - EditableSortableGroupByWithFilterExample***.